# How to emulate this lead guitar tone

Tags: guitar, tone

I'm looking to reproduce a tone that I heard in a video clip. Things like the eq settings for the amp and any other tips would help

Start at 9:23

Comment: I just head some delay + reverb, maybe a tad of compression for the sustain, humbuckers pickups, and a relatively good guitar player. Eq seems to me mostly flat, maybe some lo-cut, and to be honest, i don't find that tone thick, or even crazy good, it's an 'ok' sound.. but that's personal preference. Dialing in great guitar tones has to do with many stuff, context of the song is one big part, how good of a tone hunter you are as a guitar player... a useless tone for you, could work great in another context.. There are other questions regarding guitar tone in this forum, maybe they're helpful

Comment: I have edited the title, as I'd agree with @frcake - this is a reasonable tone, but nothing special.

Comment: Thank you @frcake for your comments. Could you guide me to another question or some other place where I can learn about how to get a good guitar tone or to eq an amp?